# Converting a (XML)String to DT_NTEXT inside a SSIS Script Component

Tags: c#, ssis, script-component

**Hey there, I have quite an Issue with an huge string from a Json . I want to write it into a Nvarchar(max) Column using the Script Component.**

The OutputColumn is set to DT_NTEXT and I am using:

`Output0Buffer.xdata.AddBlobData(System.Text.Unicode.UTF8.GetBytes(item.x_data));`

The Jsonclass Item x_data is to string:

`... public string x_data { get; set; }  ...`

The String is an XML that looks somthing like this:

`"<products>\r\n   <product>\r\n      <set>\r\n         <pindex>PKHC544</pindex>\r\n         <pvarindex><PKHC544><PKHC544.O08.MF1000></pvarindex> \r\n         <child>\r\n            <index>ZKVXXXXD</index>\r\n            <varindex><ZKVXXXXD><ZKVXXXXDD00></varindex>\r\n         </child>    \r\n      </set>\r\n   </product>\r\n</products>"`

My Error message is this:

`Error: 0xC0047062 at DF Load printcarrier_Orders, SC Import printcarrier_Orders [156]: System.ArgumentNullException: The string reference is not set to a string instance. Parameter name: s for Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.HandleUserException(Exception e) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.PrimeOutput(Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, PipelineBuffer[] buffers) at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers, IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)`

**I think I have a problem with the Encoding of this string, maybe x_data should have a different data type. All other Columns are working smoothly.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got the Issue solved, I was not checking for Null references before.
It is not working if it is not included